# UIPanGestureRecognizer to re-enable scrollview

Tags: uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I am disabling a UIScrollView when it reaches a particular offset, and would like to re-enable it in a gesture recognizer. The only issue I have is that the scrollview does not get the touch until the the users touch is lifted from the screen.

How can I re-enable the scrollview without lifting a finger?

UIScrollViews category:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

---

```
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    gestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
    gestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
    [self.bodyScrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];


- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        if (self.previousAssetsScrollViewOffset.y == -44
            && !self.bodyScrollView.scrollEnabled && !self.composeScrollView.scrollEnabled) {
            self.bodyScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
            self.composeScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you are not distinguishing between different phases (stages) of the gesture. Thus your `handlePanGesture:` is called over and over throughout the gesture, and never gives up control over the gesture so that the scroll view can detect that something is happening. Basically, you have "eaten" the entire gesture, so that the scroll view never hears about it.

However, even after you fix that, you may still have a problem, because once your gesture recognizer has recognized, no touches are delivered to other gesture recognizers, including that of the scroll view.

Comment: How do I go by delivering the touch to the scrollView? As you mentioned if I go by checking the states, it still does not fix my problem.

Comment: I said in my second paragraph that you're going to have trouble with this. It may be impossible, or you might have to do some extra work to tell the two gesture recognizers (yours and the scroll view's) that it is okay for them to recognize simultaneously. You also need your gesture recognizer to take its hands off - after `began` it must not do anything (right now it is).

Comment: hmm...So you're saying if i remove my gesture after began? Even if I remove my gesture nothing happens...I had thought - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer should allow simultaneous? But, I guess after scrollEnabled = NO this is no longer honored?

Comment: It might! You'll have to try. I don't know whether it will work.

Comment: No good =( on state changed I do [self.composeScrollView removeGestureRecognizer:self.gestureRecognizer]; but I guess the touch is still not transferred. thanks for the tips.

Comment: I don't tink you need to remove it. Just test for `changed` and `ended` and do nothing. That is what the first paragraph of my answer told you. But then, as my second paragraph says, the issue is getting the other gesture recognizer to participate.